# SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common with Spring Boot SSL

Tags: java, spring, ssl

I am trying to implement SSL for my sample Spring Boot application. I was given a `example.pem`, `example.key`, `example.csr`, `example.crt` and a `example.p7b` file by the admin for `example.com`.

I converted my `PEM` to a `DER` file by using this command:

```
openssl x509 -outform der -in example.pem -out example.der
```

Then, I converted the `DER` file to a `JKS` file as:

```
keytool -import -alias example -keystore example.jks -file example.der
```

Then, I put the `JKS` file into the `main/resources` directory and following in the `application.properties` file:

```
server.port=443

# SSL settings
server.ssl.enabled=true
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:example.jks
server.ssl.key-store-password=example
server.ssl.key-password=example
```

Now, when I hit `https://example.com` or `https://example.com:443` (doesn't matter as HTTPS is on `443`), I get the following trace:

```
04:05:10.667 [qtp555826066-15] DEBUG o.e.jetty.server.HttpConnection - 
  javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common
  at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.checkThrown(Handshaker.java:1478)
  ...
```

Did I converted the wrong file to JKS or did I do something wrong?

**EDIT:**
I use embedded Jetty server.

**UPDATE:**
When I try to add the `key` file to `pem` and get a `pkcs12` file using the command:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey example.key -in example.pem -name example -out example.pkcs12
```

I get `example.pkcs12` file but also an error saying:

```
No certificate matches private key
```

Is my `PEM` or `KEY` files corrupted?

Comment: Yes, you did something wrong, and so did the admin: he should never have given you a key; but, assuming that's legitimate, you should have got it into your JKS keystore. I think you do that by adding it to the PEM and then converting that to PKCS#12 format, and then converting that to JKS.

Comment: @EJP I tried doing that. When I try `openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey example.key -in example.pem -name example -out example.pkcs12`, I get a `pkcs12` file but also an error saying `No certificate matches private key`. Is my PEM corrupted?

Comment: That appears to mean that `example.key` doesn't match `example.pem`. Refer to admin.